# Eloquent model relation in one query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to load a Model with relationship in one SQL query. Is it possible?

For example, if i write classic eloquent query:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->hobby;
```

It will run 2 SQL queries: one for the **User** and another one for **Hobby**.
And the **User** Model instance will include the hobby data in *relations* attribute.
(The same will happen via ->with() method)

The closest i got to do this with one single SQL query is this:

```
$user = User::select(['users.*', 'hobbies.*'])
   ->join('hobbies', 'hobbies.id', 'users.hobbie_id')
   ->find(1);
```

But the problem is that the columns of **Hobby** will be in *original* attribute and mixing with **User** attributes instead of *relations* attribute as the first example.

Is it possible to do something like this but the relation data will be under to *relations* attribute?

Comment: I'm not clear about your confusion !. Make it clear, please.

Comment: I don't believe that this is possible with default eloquent. What is the reason you only want to run one query? Whats wrong with running two?

Comment: *Is it possible to do something like this but the relation data will be under to relations attribute?* **No!**

Comment: There is nothing wrong with running 2  queries. Running these kind of relationships in one query would be slower then the 2 queries, and uses more memory space. I would even advise you to only use the with() function if its really needed, so you only load the data that you really need.

Comment: In my project i have more then 2 relations for the Model. i need them available every time the Model is loaded. so it comes down to more then 2 queries when loading the Model. My idea was to make a [Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes) query with joins so every Model load will join the relations in the query. Anyway i think you answered my question about the possibility of doing somthing like this. Thank you. Also maybe @GertB. is right and it is more efficient to do separate queries. I'll check this, Thanks.

Comment: If you want to load some relations by default you can define ```$with``` property in corresponding model. you can read it here  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default

Answer (score 0):

you can change hobby's attribute name in select

```
    $user = User::select(['users.*', 'hobbies.name as hobby_name'])
   ->join('hobbies', 'hobbies.id', 'users.hobbie_id')
   ->find(1);
```

in this you can change relations attribute name